# Last url extension change as title

Tags: php

How can I select the last extension from the address and change it to title?

I have a url address:

```
www.website.com/my/contact.php
```

and I want this:

```
contact.php
```

and then change it to:

```
Contact
```

Here is my code but it doesn't work:

```
$page = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_PATH);
if (basename($page) == basename(__FILE__)) $page="" ;
function title_name() {

$title = array(
    'contact.php' => 'Contact',
    'home.php' => 'Home page'
);

 if (isset($page)) {
           $tit_a = '<title>';
           $tit = title_name();
           $tit_b = '</title>';
           $page = $tit_a . $tit . $tit_b;
  } 
}
```

and then write $page to the database

Comment: you're probably going to want to use `REQUEST_URI` instead of `HTTP_REFERER`; the latter is typically used for the page URL that referred you to the current page, if any

Comment: Do you want to get the title in www.website.com/my/contact.php i.e Contact?

Comment: yes title page.  I want it for statistics. To see which page is the most watched

Comment: just a min, pasting the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<title><?php
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on')   
         $url = "https://";   
    else  
         $url = "http://";   
       
    $url.= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$a= explode("/", $url);
$extracted= end($a);
$urlArray= explode(".", $extracted);

echo $title= $urlArray[0];
?></title>
```

Comment: It's better, but the result is not what I want. The result came out to me like this: my/contact  I need it to go like this: contact

Comment: Alright, can you wait for 2 more mins? I will edit the code to do that.

Comment: One more question. If I only have the url www.website.com/ so the title does not appear at all

Comment: yes, you have the edit the code like that.

Comment: And one more thing, if my answer is helpful, could you upvote my answer? I want to increase my reputation. ;)

Comment: Of course, but how would I adjust it so that I have HOME as the main page instead of an empty place

Comment: I have edited it again, and this time it will work for any url.